# Update textbox on checkbox selection

Tags: jquery

How would I update my textbox when checkbox values are adjusted?

For example if the textbox says 1-6 when checkbox 1 to 6 is selected, and 3 is unchecked, I would like the textbox to say 1,2,4-6 or 1,2,4,5,6. How do I go about doing this.

This is my code so far and my jsFiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/dYsg7/4/:

```
// slider

$(".slider_weekRange2").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 15,
    step: 1,
    values: [1, 12],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(".search_weekRange2").val(ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);
        $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", false);
        $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').slice(ui.values[0] - 1, ui.values[1]).prop("checked", true);
    }
});
$(".search_weekRange2").val($(".slider_weekRange2").slider("values", 0) +
    "-" + $(".slider_weekRange2").slider("values", 1));

// weeks

     // no weeks

$('.week_none').click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", false);
        $(".search_weekRange2").val('');
});

        // all week

$('.week_all').click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", true);
        $(".search_weekRange2").val('1-15');
});

        // weeks 1-12

$('.week_term').click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", false);
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').slice(0, 12).prop("checked", true);
        $(".search_weekRange2").val('1-12');
});

        // odd weeks

$('.week_odd').click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", false);
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]:even').prop("checked", true);
        $(".search_weekRange2").val('1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15');
});

        // even weeks

$('.week_even').click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]').prop("checked", false);
    $('input:checkbox[name="weeks_1"]:odd').prop("checked", true);
        $(".search_weekRange2").val('2,4,6,8,10,12,14');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dYsg7/5/

This is the code I added:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    var s = [];
    $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            s.push($(this).next().text());
        }
    });
   $(".search_weekRange2").val(s.join(','));
});
```

When a checkbox is clicked, go through each checkbox, and add it's label's text (the next item after that) to an array if it's checked. After collecting all the checked checkboxes, join them all with a comma, and then assign it to the output.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an onChange listener to your checkboxes and calling a function that will create your string and update the check box?